# Calculate average of items at particular index in a python list

Tags: python, list

I have a python list like this:

```
a = ['1111', 1, '1112', 15, '1113', 21, '2221', 1, '2222', 34, '3331', 1, '3332', 54, '3333', 65]
```

The strings in the odd places represent the id and step number. The first three characters are id and the last is step number. Whereas, the numbers in even indices represent duration.

Now, I want to calculate the average duration for every step number.

For example, if I have to calculate the average of the second step the list items I need to consider will be like this:

`['1112', 15, '2222', 34, '3332', 54]` and average will be `(15 + 34 + 54) / 3`. 3 because there are 3 strings which have step number 2.

Although in case of 3 there are only 2 processes. `['1113', 21, '3333', 65]`. So average will be `(21 + 65) / 2`.

I have no clue right now, how to solve this. That's why I'm not including the code snippet.

P.S: I do not want to use any external library for this problem.

Comment: You could take a pen and paper, write down the steps by your `logic` and then work out `pseudo code` first then share here -where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```py
a = ['1111', 1, '1112', 15, '1113', 21, '2221', 1, '2222', 34, '3331', 1, '3332', 54, '3333', 65]

def step_avg(l):
    out_dict = dict()
    l = {l[i]: l[i+1] for i in range(0, len(l), 2)}
    for string in l:
            step = int(string[3:])
            if step not in out_dict:
                    out_dict[step] = (l[string], 1) # sum_of_values, num_of_values
            else:
                    sum_of_values, num_of_values = out_dict[step]
                    out_dict[step] = (sum_of_values + l[string], num_of_values + 1)
    for step in out_dict:
            sum_of_values, num_of_values = out_dict[step]
            out_dict[step] = (sum_of_values / num_of_values)
    return out_dict

print(step_avg(a))
```

output:

```sh
{1: 1.0, 2: 34.333333333333336, 3: 43.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to filter out every second (third, etc.) step:

```
every_second_step = [d for id, d in zip(a[::2], a[1::2]) if id[-1] == '2']
```

And to find an average:

```
second_step_mean = sum(every_second_step) / len(every_second_step)
```

Same for every third step:

```
every_third_step = [d for id, d in zip(a[::2], a[1::2]) if id[-1] == '3']
third_step_mean = sum(every_third_step) / len(every_third_step)
```

Comment: it is giving third step mean = 11 but its 43 if you calculate it manually.

Comment: Aha. I misunderstood the logic. Will update it

Comment: Done..............

Comment: Sum over len [breaks in certain edge cases](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0450/#rationale). That's why statistics.mean() exists.

Comment: @TommyA. `The built-in sum can lose accuracy when dealing with floats of wildly differing magnitude.` These are not floats nor they are of wildly differing magnitude.